# How to override widget asset? (yii2)

Tags: widget, yii2, assets

I have Asset file which is located in 
`vendor/vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget/src/Asset.php` 
and i want to override it, because i want to use changed `redactor.min.js`file which is located in `web/js/redactor.min.js`
I tried to put this code to components in web.php :`

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'vova07\imperavi' => [
            'sourcePath' => 'vova07\imperavi\assets',
            'js' => ['redactor.min.js', '@app/web/js/redactor.min.js']
        ]
    ]
],
```

but it does not work

Comment: I think `@app` is not allowed here. You have to specify files that can be found relative to `sourcePath` directory.

Answer (score 7):

Have a try:

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'vova07\imperavi\Asset' => [
            'sourcePath' => null,
            'js' => [
                'js/redactor.min.js'
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

In section [Customizing Asset Bundles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles):

> You can configure multiple asset bundles similarly through `yii\web\AssetManager::$bundles`. The *array keys should be **the class names (without the leading backslash)** of the asset bundles*, ...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but i faced the same issue, @drodata almost had the solution. The web path and url must be set in orther to point to the web folder correctly:

```
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => [
            'vova07\imperavi\Asset' => [
                'sourcePath' => null,
                'basePath' => '@webroot',
                'baseUrl' => '@web',
                'js' => [
                    'js/redactor.min.js'
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```